# Every time I wake my Macbook it switches applications after wake. How do I fix this?

Tags: macos

Whenever I close my MacBook, and then come back after it's been asleep, I'll open it, and it'll make a sound while it's waking the harddrive, which is normal. But then after that it'll switch the whichever application is active with the second-most active on in the tab-switcher. Does anyone know what would cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [Apple Support article overviews a similar issue](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3268136?start=0&tstart=0). This is on a Early 2010 macbook pro, and OP on the linked thread tied the cause to the "require password after 5 minutes" setting in Security and Privacy. OP solved this issue by switching to "require password immediately"

Have you done all updates up to 10.7.5?

Comment: I'm on 10.7.5, and my require password is set to require it after 15, I guess I'll just turn it off.


edit: and it worked! thank you.

Comment: Thank you! This has bugged me for forever but I never managed to find the right keywords to google it properly.